How to get container of model in EditorTemplate, ASP.NET Core 8.0
I'm looking for possibility to retrieve container in EditorTemplate (ASP.NET Core 8.0).
In .NET 4.6 there is property for that:
ViewData.ModelMetadata.Container

but there is no such property in .NET 8. I'm migrating the project from .NET 4.6 to .NET 8.
I tried to use ModelExplorer but without success.
Code of EditorTemplate for clarity:
var attribute = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType
                        .GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
                        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MediaPickerAttribute), false)
                        .Select(a => a as MediaPickerAttribute)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

// object container = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Container;
object container = ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetModelExplorerForType(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType, Model).Container;

List<MediaDTO> valueObject = new List<MediaDTO>();

if (attribut.SelectedValuesProperty != null)
{
    valueObject = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType
                          .GetProperty(attribut.SelectedValuesProperty)
                          .GetValue(container) as List<MediaDTO>;
}

MediaPickerAttribute:
public class MediaPickerAttribute : UIHintAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary for selected item (if any)
    /// </summary>
    public string SelectedValuesProperty { get; set; }

    public bool YoutubeAllowed { get; set; } = true;
    public bool Multiple { get; set; } = true;

    // .....
}

Container model MediaEditDto:
public class MediaEditDto 
{
    // .....

    // this property contains list of 
    [MediaPicker(SelectedValuesProperty = nameof(RelatedMedia), Multiple = true, YoutubeAllowed = false)]
    [Display(Name = nameof(Resources.Photo.RelatedMedia), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Photo))]
    public List<Guid>? PhotosIds { get; set; }

    public List<MediaDTO>? RelatedMedia { get; set; } = new List<MediaDTO>();
}

Edit.cshtml edit view:
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group ">
         <label asp-for="Dto.PhotosIds" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                 Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dto.PhotosIds)
                 <span asp-validation-for="Dto.PhotosIds" class="text-danger has-error help-block"></span>
              </div>
    </div>
</div>

I tried to retrieve container model (MediaEditDto) with different approaches through ModelExplorer, but I always get null, ie:
// object container = ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetModelExplorerForType(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType, Model).Container;

I'm expecting to get container pointing to object of type MediaEditDto and valueObject that contains RelatedMedia value.
This example is simplified, some EditorTemplates needs more than one property to retrieve from container model, so get that model is critical.

To retrieve the container model in an EditorTemplate in ASP.NET Core 8, you must access the model metadata differently than .NET Framework 4.6. The ViewData.ModelMetadata.Container property does not exist in ASP.NET Core, but you can still achieve your goal using the ModelExplorer.
Here is a solution that should work for your scenario. First, let's adjust the EditorTemplate to correctly retrieve the container model and access its properties.
var container = ViewData.ModelExplorer.Container?.Model;

var attribute = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType
    .GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MediaPickerAttribute), false)
    .Select(a => a as MediaPickerAttribute)
    .FirstOrDefault();

List<MediaDTO> valueObject = new List<MediaDTO>();

if (attribute != null && attribute.SelectedValuesProperty != null && container != null)
{
    var selectedValuesProperty = container.GetType().GetProperty(attribute.SelectedValuesProperty);
    if (selectedValuesProperty != null)
    {
        valueObject = selectedValuesProperty.GetValue(container) as List<MediaDTO>;
    }
}

You can continue using Html.EditorFor as you were:
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group ">
         <label asp-for="Dto.PhotosIds" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dto.PhotosIds)
                 <span asp-validation-for="Dto.PhotosIds" class="text-danger has-error help-block"></span>
              </div>
    </div>
</div>


You need to use ViewData.ModelExplorer.Container instead of ModelMetadata.
